# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac {e^n}{n}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Is the below series convergent? How should I find out so?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac {e^n}{n}$$
I tried to use Leibniz test but I failed finding the right answer.

Comment: What is the limit of the summed expression?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to find out whether series converges or not. n goes to infinity.

Comment: have you tried ratio test?

Comment: Travis is asking you to think about the limits of the terms in your series. If you do so, you will get an immediate answer to your question.

Comment: The series diverges to -1.

Comment: @CountIblis: that is a contradictory statement...

Comment: @abiessu [Divergent series converge faster than convergent series because they don't have to converge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_F._Carrier).

Comment: Well, of course you cannot use Leibniz test. Leibniz test says that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges **if** $a_n$ satisfies **three** conditions. And $\dfrac{e^n}{n}$ does not satisfy two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac {e^n}{n}$$ diverges because of the use of the series ratio test (which someone suggested you use). Remember, that test says if $\exists \ \text {an} \ N \ \text {so that} \ \forall \ n \geq N, a_n \neq 0, \text {and}$ $$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert \frac {a_{n + 1}}{a_n} \rvert$$ the series converges if $L < 1$. If $L > 1$, then the series diverges. If $L = 1$, the series is inconclusive. To prove this, let's work the limit out: $$\lvert \frac {a_{n + 1}}{a_n} \rvert = \left\lvert \frac{(-1)^{(n + 1)\frac{e^{(n + 1)}}{n + 1}}}{(-1)^n\frac {e^n}{n}}\right\rvert$$ Which simplifies to: $$\left\lvert \frac{en}{n + 1} \right\rvert$$ When we plug that into our limit, we get: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\left\lvert \frac{en}{n + 1}\right\rvert\right) = e = 2.718281828459045...$$ Since $L = e$, and $e > 1$, that means that $L > 1$. So, the series diverges.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac {e^n}{n}\neq 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Is the limit of the absolute value of the term equal to zero?